# How to add a prefix to all the end points in Servant?

Tags: rest, haskell, servant

I have kind of a hello world app in Haskell servant, here's a part of it:

```
type API = 
  "my_items" :> Get '[JSON] [MyItem]
  :<|> "my_items" :> Capture "id" Int :> Get '[JSON] MyItem
  -- ...................
```

and the urls are:

```
  localhost/my_items
  localhost/my_items/123
```

How can I add a prefix to the existing urls and others I'll create:

```
  localhost/api/v1/my_items
  localhost/api/v1/my_items/123
  localhost/api/v1/.....
```

?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just create another type:

```
type APIv1 = "api" :> "v1" :> API
```