# Haskell Servant: How to prefix routes when using generics?

Tags: haskell, servant

I'm using Servant generic, and have a datatype for my routes:

```
data Routes route = Routes
  { getLiveness :: route :- GetLiveness,
    getReadiness :: route :- GetReadiness,

    getAuthVerifyEmailToken :: route :- GetAuthVerifyEmailToken,
    postAuthEmail :: route :- PostAuthEmail,
    ...
  }
  deriving (Generic)

type BackendPrefix = "backend"

type AuthPrefix = "auth"

type GetLiveness = BackendPrefix :> "liveness" :> Get '[JSON] Text

type GetReadiness = BackendPrefix :> "readiness" :> Get '[JSON] Text

type GetAuthVerifyEmailToken = AuthPrefix :> "verify" :> "email" :> Capture "token" JWT :> RedirectResponse '[PlainText] NoContent

type PostAuthEmail = AuthPrefix :> "email" :> ReqBody '[JSON] AuthEmailRequest :> PostNoContent
```

The first two use the same prefix `"backend"`, and all other's have an `"auth"` prefix.

However, I now want to change the `"auth`" prefix to "backend/auth". So I tried chaging:

`type AuthPrefix = BackendPrefix :> "auth"`

This results in an error

```
>     • Expected a type, but
>       ‘"auth"’ has kind
>       ‘ghc-prim-0.6.1:GHC.Types.Symbol’
>     • In the second argument of ‘(:>)’, namely ‘"auth"’
>       In the type ‘BackendPrefix :> "auth"’
>       In the type declaration for ‘AuthPrefix’
>    |
> 34 | type AuthPrefix = BackendPrefix :> "auth"
>    |
```

So I googled and found you can do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36243779/how-to-add-a-prefix-to-all-the-end-points-in-servant) when not using generic you can do:

```
type APIv1 = "api" :> "v1" :> API
```

But I couldn't figure out how to do this with generics.

I guess that leaves two questions:

1. What does the above error mean, and can I use something like `type AuthPrefix = BackendPrefix :> "auth"` to create a more complex prefix?
2. Is there a way to prefix some routes with one prefix, and the other routes with a different prefix, when using generics in Servant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:>` is `infixr 4`, which means it's right-associative. Consider this type:

```
type GetFoo = "backend" :> "auth" :> "foo" :> Get '[JSON] Text
```

It's interpreted as if you parenthesized it like this:

```
type GetFoo = "backend" :> ("auth" :> ("foo" :> Get '[JSON] Text))
```

With the type synonym you tried, it would get parenthesized like this instead:

```
type GetFoo = ("backend" :> "auth") :> ("foo" :> Get '[JSON] Text)
```

And that's clearly not the same thing, and in fact not even valid.

---

To help understand, consider this ordinary Haskell code with no advanced types:

```
xs = 1:2:3:4:5:6:[]
ys = 1:2:4:8:16:32:[]
```

Now imagine you tried to write this:

```
zs = 1:2
xs = zs:3:4:5:6:[]
ys = zs:4:8:16:32:[]
```

The reason it doesn't work is the exact same reason you can't have your type synonym.

---

One final example:

```
x = 2 ^ 3 ^ 2 -- evaluates to 2 ^ (3 ^ 2) = 512
```

```
y = 2 ^ 3
x = y ^ 2 -- evaluates to (2 ^ 3) ^ 2 = 64
```

Comment: Perfect explanation! Thank you so much for this!

Answer (score 3):

The definition of [`:>`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-0.18.3/docs/Servant-API.html#t::-62-) is

```
data (path :: k) :> (a :: *)
```

Notice that the right part must have kind `*`, also known as [`Type`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-Kind.html#t:Type). This is the kind of "normal" Haskell types like `Int` or `Bool` that have lifted values.

However, in the type-level expression `BackendPrefix :> "auth"` the kind of `"auth"` is [`Symbol`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/GHC-TypeLits.html#t:Symbol), which is the kind of type-level strings. The kinds don't match and that causes the type error.

(You might wonder, how come that paths like `"foo" :> "bar" :>  Post '[JSON] User` do work? The reason is that a fully applied [`Post`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-0.18.3/docs/Servant-API-Verbs.html#t:Post) has kind `Type`, a fully applied `:>` also has kind `Type`, and `:>` associates to the right, like `"foo" :> ("bar" :>  Post '[JSON] User)`, so it all checks out.)

The solution? Perhaps give `AuthPrefix` a type parameter, like

```
type AuthPrefix restofpath = BackendPrefix :> "auth" :> restofpath
```

That way we won't end the route fragment in a `Symbol`.

We have to use `AuthPrefix` a little differently now:

```
 AuthPrefix ("email" :> ReqBody '[JSON] AuthEmailRequest :> PostNoContent)
```

This is because the new definition already takes care of applying the `:>` to the rest of the path.